# Parse json in command line terminal

Tags: json, terminal, jq

I want to use `jq` for processing my `json` file in terminal. I am trying this command:

```
cat json.txt | jq 'name'
```

it's showing me

```
-bash: /usr/bin/jq: cannot execute binary file
```

Expected result:

```
Google
```

where `json.txt` is indeed a valid `json` file. I tried to check whether `jq` is installed correctly. Here's what I am getting:

```
 brew install jq
```

it's showing me:

```
Warning: jq-1.3 already installed
```

I am using `mac`. Anybody has any idea? The `json.txt` file is:

```
 {
    "name": "Google",
    "location":
            {
                    "street": "1600 Amphitheatre Parkway",
                    "city": "Mountain View",
                    "state": "California",
                    "country": "US"
            },
    "employees":
            [
                    {
                            "name": "Michael",
                            "division": "Engineering"
                    },
                    {
                            "name": "Laura",
                            "division": "HR"
                    },
                    {
                            "name": "Elise",
                            "division": "Marketing"
                    }
            ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Regarding getting your expected result, the filter you want to use is:

```
.name
```

Note the `.`.  You want to get the value of the `name` property.

As for the error, I don't know what your environment is but it seems to indicate that you've installed the wrong version of jq that isn't compatible with your OS.  Look for a *good* tutorial on how to get it installed on your machine.